# Exclude 29 February from time interval

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I want to exclude 29th February from my calculations of no of complete days  between two dates. Excluding the corner values of the interval.

Test scenarios :

```
1 March 2012 - 28th February 2012  = should give 0 days.
1 March 2012 - 26th February 2012  = should give 2 days.
1 March 2013 - 28th February 2012  = should give 365 days and not 366 days.
1 March 2017 - 28th February 2012  = should give 365*5 =1825 days and not 1827 days.
```

Currently I parse year and check if there is any leap year between dates and then check if the interval has 29th February. Is there any way to figure if any particular interval has a particular day and number of occurrences if the interval spans over no of years.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to exclude Feb 29th?

Comment: @peter-lawrey I am writing code for a Insurance Company and they have a policy to not charge premium for 29 th of February in case the policy is surrendered or prorated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Java-esque pseudo-code should work.  It would also allow you to add other filters if you wish:

```
int daysExcludingLeapYearDay(Date start, Date end)
{
    if(end.isBefore(start))
    {
        return filterOutLeapYearDays(daysBetween(end, start)).size();
    }

    return filterOutLeapYearDays(daysBetween(start, end)).size();
}

List<Date> filterOutLeapYearDays(List<Date> days)
{
    List<Date> daysExcludingLeapYearDays = 
             days
             .filter(d -> !isFeb29(d))
             .toList());

    return daysExcludingLeapYearDays;
}

List<Date> daysBetween(Date start, Date end) 
{
    List<Date> days = new List();

    for (Date day = start; day.isBefore(end); day = day.plusOneDay()) 
    {
        days.add(day);
    }

    return days
}

boolean isFeb29(Date date) 
{
    return date.month == FEBRUARY && date.day == 29;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

but it isn't caused by feb 29th, it's right.

if you compare 1 March 2012 and 28th February 2012  will return 1 day, and with 29th will return 2 days. The difference between these two dates is one day.

To return 0 days how you want you should compare two same dates, like 1 March 2012 and 1 March 2012.

I think you're mistaking that ^^.

Comment: I am talking of complete days between two dates excluding the ends. I will update the question for more clarity.

Comment: humm, I don't know if it's possible, but if you change the year to 1900 for instance just to compare the two dates?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of 360 day years, but this is the first time I've encountered a 365 day year.

Your best bet is to calculate the difference between your dates in days, and subtract out all of the February 29th's that you encounter.

Which means you need a routine that will go through your range of dates and return a count of the number of February 29th's that you encounter.

I have no idea how to do this in JodaTime, but the basic algorithm would be

- Convert the start date to the number of days since 1 January 1970.
- Convert the end date to the number of days since 1 January 1970.
- Loop from start day to end day one day at a time.
- Convert loop day back to a date.
- if the date is 29 Feb, add 1 to a counter
- After finishing the loop, return the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can acheive it as follows, where `startDate` and `endDate` are javascript `Date` objects.

```
function calculateDays(startDate,endDate){
    var oneDay = 86400000; //ms per day
    var difference = Math.ceil((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / oneDay); 
    var totFeb29s = findTotalFeb29s(startDate,endDate);
    return  parseInt(difference)+parseInt(1)-parseInt(totFeb29s);    
}    
function findTotalFeb29s(startDate,endDate){
    var totalFeb29s = 0;
    var startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
    var endYear = endDate.getFullYear();
    for(var year=startYear;year<=endYear;year++){
        var dt = new Date(year, 1, 29);
        var isLeap = dt.getMonth() == 1;
        if(isLeap==true && startDate<=dt && dt<=endDate){
           totalFeb29s = parseInt(totalFeb29s)+parseInt(1);
        }
    }
    return totalFeb29s;
}
```

Comment: why are you providing a javascript answer? the question does not ask for this.